# Change right click behavior for touchpad

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I have a new Lenovo T440p (which has an apple-like clickpad) and in windows, the touchpad behaves as I want it to, the entire surface behaves the same when clicked, and to right click, I click with two fingers. On linux, however, when I click on the bottom right portion of the touchpad, it registers as a right click, which I do not like. I have looked in the synaptics configuration GUI but couldn't find an option to change this behaviour. Am I missing something or is there some other way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: I think if you read this through you will find what you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/396123/want-left-and-right-mouse-buttons-to-both-map-to-select

Comment: Didn't quite work, but pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I first met with success when I tried disabling the soft button for right click by moving it out of the bounds of the trackpad. This worked, but since my laptop also has a trackpoint with buttons integrated into the clickpad, I instead moved the soft button to the right click area of the track point.

I couldn't get these changes to persist with the `xorg.conf` file (which I think I should be able to, I'm just incompetent), but I got it to work as a `lightdm` startup script.

I made a script which executed

```
synclient RightButtonAreaBottom=2500 RightButtonAreaTop=0
```

and set that as a `lightdm` startup script and it all works nicely.

I'm still not perfectly happy, for example, when I click in certain positions, the cursor moves down about 5 pixels, which the windows drivers seem to be able to compensate for (also this was never a problem when running linux on my macbook pro, which also had a clickpad). I would also like to have three finger middle click, but it's not vital.